# Skipped 108 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, android-animation

現在ボタンを押すとアニメーションが表示されるようなプログラムを組んでいるのですが、ボタンを押してからアニメーションが表示されるまでの間に時間があり、スムーズにアニメーションが表示されません。ログを見てみると、`Skipped 108 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` や、`GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 1% free 23795K/23900K, paused 10ms, total 10ms` などと表示されています。アニメーションの際の各画像サイズが大きすぎるのだと思うのですが、色々と調べて画像サイズを減らそうとしてみても、画像が荒くなったりと中々思うようにいきません。解決策としてはどういった選択肢をとればよいでしょうか？下記にコードを記します。すみませんが、宜しくお願いします。

```
public class AnimationActivity extends Activity {
    private Activity mActivity = this;
    ImageView animationImageView;
    AnimationConfig animationConfig;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_animation);

        animationImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.animation_imageview);

        animationConfig = new AnimationConfig(mActivity, animationImageView, 2000, 2000, 50);
        animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_01);
        animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_02);
        animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_03);
        animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_04);
        animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_05);
        animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_06);
        animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_07);
        animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_08);
        animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_09);
        animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_10);
        animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_11);
        animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_12);
        animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_13);
        animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_14);
        animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_15);
        animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_16);
        animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_17);
        animationConfig.setAnimationFrame(R.drawable.slot_18);

        animationConfig.startAnimation();
    }
}

public class AnimationConfig {
    private Activity mActivity;
    private int mDuration;
    private int mOffset;
    private int mEachImageShowTime;
    private AnimationSet mAnimationSet;
    private ImageView mAnimationImageView;
    private AnimationDrawable anim;
    private List<Drawable> mFrameList = new ArrayList<Drawable>();

    public AnimationConfig(Activity activity, ImageView imageView, int duration, int offset, int eachImageShowTime) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mAnimationImageView = imageView;
        mDuration = duration;
        mOffset = offset;
        mEachImageShowTime = eachImageShowTime;
    }

    public void setAnimationFrame(int image) {
        mFrameList.add(mActivity.getResources().getDrawable(image));
    }

    public void startAnimation() {
        setFrameAnimation(mAnimationImageView, mEachImageShowTime);
        mAnimationImageView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                anim.start();
            }
        });
        mAnimationImageView.startAnimation(setFadeAnimation(mDuration, mOffset));
    }

    public void setFrameAnimation(ImageView imageView, int sec) {
        mAnimationImageView = imageView;
        anim = new AnimationDrawable();
        for (Drawable frame:mFrameList) { anim.addFrame(frame, sec); }
        anim.setOneShot(false);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(anim);
    }

    public AnimationSet setFadeAnimation(int duration, final int offset){
        AlphaAnimation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        final AlphaAnimation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
        fadeIn.setDuration(duration);

        fadeIn.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                fadeOut.setStartOffset(offset);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });

        fadeOut.setDuration(duration);
        fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                mAnimationImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mAnimationSet.setFillAfter(true);
                mActivity.finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });

        mAnimationSet = new android.view.animation.AnimationSet(false); {
            mAnimationSet.addAnimation(fadeIn);
            mAnimationSet.addAnimation(fadeOut);
        }

        return mAnimationSet;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://tinypng.com/ で画像のサイズを圧縮してみてはいかがでしょうか？
画像が荒くなることもないかと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご紹介いただいたサイトで画像を圧縮したところ、とても動作が軽くなりました！ありがとうございます。